# User input of a name

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I have attempted to create a program that will ask a user for the amount of books in a library. Then it will ask for those book titles and store them in an array. The problem is that the program is only asking for the book Name once when it is supposed to ask for the number of books that are in the library.

I have a feeling that the problem is within the while loop and that the scanner is messing up but I am not sure.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LIBBOOKS {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numB = 0;
        int count = 0;;
        boolean libEmpty = true;
        String nameArray[];
        String bookName = "";

        System.out.println("Enter Number of Books: ");
        Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);     
        numB = value.nextInt();

        nameArray = new String[numB];

        while(libEmpty)
        {
            Scanner sValue = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Book Name: ");
            while(sValue.hasNextLine())
            {
                bookName = sValue.nextLine();
            }

            count++;
            nameArray[count] = bookName;
            if(numB < count)
            {
                System.out.println("Capacity Reached");
                libEmpty = false;
            }
            sValue.close();
        } 

        value.close();
        System.out.println("Book Listing Entered:");
        for(int i = 1; i > count; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(" " + nameArray[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

When I run the program this is what I get:

```
Enter Number of Books: 
4
Enter Book Name: 
apples
corn
peaches
oranges
```

The program should be asking me each time what the name is before I get a chance to enter another name. 
What I expect to happen:

```
Enter Number of Books:
4
Enter Book Name:
apples
Enter Book Name:
corn
Enter Book Name:
peaches
Enter Book Name:
oranges

Capacity Reached
Book Listing Entered:
corn apples peaches oranges
```

Comment: Can you put the expected output as well ?

Comment: It seems you could use some complimentary [debugging skills](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this code. You create multiple scanners. There's no need for them, and while they may not hurt you, you should just create one:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Your class name doesn't fit with Java naming conventions, which is to used mixed case for class names. There are a few other minor style issues I'll mention later.

But the two biggest problems are that you don't clear the trailing newline after you read the number of books, and that you read the book names in a tight loop without doing anything with them.

When you use `scanner.nextInt()` the scanner will read a number and stop as soon as it reaches the end of that number, even though you typed an entire line.

Suppose you type 4 and press Enter. The following characters are in the buffer: `4` `\n`

The scanner will read just the 4, convert it to an `int` and return it. The next time you call `scanner.nextLine()` it will see the `\n` and return an empty line. Which means you need to clear that newline before you try to read in the book names. You can do that with a call to `scanner.nextLine()`.

If it wasn't for your other error, you would be asking us why the first book name comes up blank. Now, on to that other error.

```
System.out.println("Enter Book Name: ");
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    bookName = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

What this code does is read a line, throw it away, read another line, throw it away, and so on forever. The only way this will end is if it hits end of file which won't happen since you're reading from a terminal, not a file, or if you kill the JVM by pressing Ctrl-C.

You keep reading book names, but you don't do anything with them. And your question says that you expect to be prompted each time, but the prompt isn't in the loop. What you want to do is something like this:

```
scanner.nextLine(); // clear the newline after the number of books
while (count < numB)
{
    System.out.println("Enter Book Name:");
    bookName = scanner.nextLine();
    nameArray[count] = bookName;
    count++;
}
```

Except now there's no reason for the `bookName` variable to even exist. It's only used to take a name, and then put it into the array. You might as well just read directly into the array:

```
scanner.nextLine(); // clear the newline after the number of books
while (count < numB)
{
    System.out.println("Enter Book Name:");
    nameArray[count] = scanner.nextLine();
    count++;
}
```

Now, there's one more bug you're going to hit once you've read the books, but first one minor point about a Scanner. This isn't hurting you, but it isn't really correct:

```
scanner.close();
```

You don't want to close this scanner. It is a good habit to close files, but there is a principle for when you should close something, and it is this: You should close anything you open, but only things that you open.

You didn't open `System.in`. You just wrapped a `Scanner` around it. So because you didn't open it, you don't want to close it. Since closing the terminal doesn't actually do anything, there's no harm here, but it isn't strictly correct to do it.

On the other hand, if you had opened a `FileInputStream` and wrapped a `Scanner` around *that*, you would definitely want to close the scanner so that the *file you opened* would get closed properly.

Okay, now on to printing out the books!

```
for (int i = 1; i > count; i++)
{
    System.out.println(" " + nameArray[i]);
}
```

There are two different problems here. First, your loop conditions are wrong. You want to start at `0` and continue while `i` is *less than* `nameArray.length`. (`count` and `numB` should have the same value as `nameArray.length`, but an array knows how long it is, so you should rely on that rather than a variable that may happen to have the same value.) Here's what the correct `for` loop would look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(" " + nameArray[i]);
}
```

However, ever since Java 5 there's a better way: The Enhanced For Loop:

```
for (String bookName : nameArray)
{
    System.out.println(" " + bookName);
}
```

That way, there is no danger of getting the array indices wrong.

One final point: naming is hard, and there's nothing wrong with the names you've chosen, but I would have called the array `books` and the name of the book `title`, and so I would have written this last loop:

```
for (String title : books) {
    System.out.println(" " + title);
}
```

Comment: I was typing a answer mentioning these. But you took it. This is more good than what trying to post. Nice hit @DavidC

Answer (score 2):

Simply cut this line:

```
System.out.println("Enter Book Name: ");
```

And paste it inside the loop where you enter book names:

```
while(sValue.hasNextLine())
  {
     System.out.println("Enter Book Name: ");
     bookName = sValue.nextLine();
  }
```

Comment: You need to consume the line after the number first

Comment: You also need to *do* something with the book name. This will read a bunch of book names, retaining only the last one.